# magento 2.2.6 install via composer

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, localhost

I can't Install Magento 2.2.6 via composer on macOS High Sierra + I'm use MAMP Pro and getting some problems :

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
```

This is extensions from  **php.ini** :

```
    ; Extensions

MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apcu.so
MAMP_apc_MAMPextension=apc.so
extension=imap.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so

MAMP_Imagick_MAMPextension=imagick.so
MAMP_Tidy_MAMPextension=tidy.so
MAMP_Oauth_MAMPextension=oauth.so
MAMP_Igbinary_MAMPextension=igbinary.so
MAMP_Memcached_MAMPextension=memcached.so
MAMP_Redis_MAMPextension=redis.so
;extension=uploadprogress.so
;extension=yaml.so
```

Also I'm using next commands :

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt
```

My php version - 7.0.31
Apache - Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing with `--ignore-platform-reqs` this will tell composer to ignore the required extensions check.

Comment: wow, installing begin, if it’s cool - I check up your answer

Comment: I need your help one-more time 

When I'm writing `bin/magento setup:install --admin-firstname=pavel --admin-lastname=konchych --admin-email=admin@example.com  --admin-user=pavelkonchych --admin-password=xdemonx1234 --db-password=root` - I have error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

                               
  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed`

Answer (score 0):

**For Creating BackEnd User need to run following command.**

> bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin"
>   --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"